# Working with PHP and Java EE simultaneously

Tags: java, php, jakarta-ee

I am borrowing a complete eCommerce website with backend(admin) interface built in PHP from my friend. What I want to do is to parallelly build an OMS in Java EE, but a restriction is that I can't use the DB that the PHP website is using. I want to track all orders right from the PHP controller class and build up a separate backend(admin) system.

Suppose the PHP website is using MVC, then all the order requests are to come to the controller class. I want to fetch that data as soon as an HTTP order request is placed by a client and store it in the OMS built in Java EE.

I would like to know what the best possible ways are by which I can let Java EE and PHP communicate in order to track some specific HTTP requests.

Comment: Can you clear up what you are trying to do? It's not clear from the question. I'm not sure what the PHP piece is doing and what you want the J2EE system to do

Comment: @AdrianRodriguez I have edited my question, I hope now it explains what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ways which you may to investigate for you needs:

- You could try to make implementation of communication using **PHP/Java Bridge** http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/
- You could try to use **Quercus** http://quercus.caucho.com/. It is Caucho Technology's 100% Java implementation of PHP 5 released.
- You could make for example REST API in our Java EE application to make integration with different API-customers (such as PHP fronted).

I prefer last solution, because it's more flexible (you could change fronted technology stack in your needs)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the [apache solr for Typo3](http://www.typo3-solr.com/en/solr-for-typo3/) project which levereages communication between the [typo 3](http://www.typo3.org) cms framework (php) and the solr project (Java EE)